# Проблемы с подключением bzip2 к проекту Qt/C++

Tags: c++, qt, bz2

Пытаюсь подключить стороннюю библиотеку. Собираю библиотеку, генерируются следующие файлы:[image: введите сюда описание изображения] Подключаю библиотеку в QtCreator'е:

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/bzip2
LIBS += -L$$PWD/bzip2 -llibbz2
```

Но получаю только сообщение об ошибке:

```
ld: library not found for -llibbz2
```

При этом путь до библиотеки определился верно. Что я сделал не так?

Comment: Должно быть `-lbz2`

Comment: `-lbz2`, без префикса... и смотри/покажи лог сборки, если не поможет...

Comment: `-lbz2` помогло, большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-llibbz2` надо заменить на `-lbz2`. Спасибо @VTT и @Fat-Zer